# "one-to-one correspondence with files in a file system"

Tags: c#, specifications, language-specifications

I have read in the [c# language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664658(v=vs.71).aspx) :

> Source files typically have a one-to-one correspondence with files in a file system, but this correspondence is not required

What does this exactly mean ?

Comment: Interestingly I found a similar definition for other programming languages, where the term `source files` is replaced by `compilation unit`. That term is also mentioned in the C# language definition, but not used here, even though I'd think it would make more sense.

Comment: My guess the author want to point out that "what you see is not necessarily what is inside file" and vise-versa. Because something you may not see (new line can be `\n` or `\n\r` or `\r\n`, this you don't see), there are questions around where the problem lies in using special character (invisible character) in `string` literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the line before it says:

> A source file is an ordered sequence of Unicode characters

That means a "source file" doesn't necessarily have to be a file on the file system. It could be any old stream of bytes that represent characters in UTF-16. It could come from a memory stream, or from a network, or from any old place. But *usually* it's a file on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I think it literally means that each source file is represented by a single file on the system.

For example, say I have some source code:

```
Using System;

namespace Test 
{
    public class Program 
    {
        private static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

This can be saved to the file system as `Program.cs`. We now have some source code which is being represented by a single file on the system.

> but this correspondence is not required

Suggests that a source file does not always exist on the system. For example, the source could exist as a "sequence of Unicode characters" instead, which could be stored somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 0):

With visual studio, you can "link" a source file within a project.
If you place a source file in a project, and link the same source file in a different project (i.e. share the same source code in 2 different projects), you end having 2 sources files linked to a single file.

I usually use this feature in solutions having more than one project: the shared source code is something like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.0")]
```

So when complied, every assembly in my solution have the same version number.